# How to Convert a C++ Structure into C# Structure

Tags: c#-2.0

I need to  convert a complex C++ structure into C# Structure,I have converted other structures in C#, this one contains some Two Dimensional array that is what the problem how to change it,Here is my structure,

this is other structure, which I Converted properly,

C++:

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE                sSerialNumber[DH_SERIALNO_LEN];     BYTE                byAlarmInPortNum;       
    BYTE                byAlarmOutPortNum;  
    BYTE                byDiskNum; 
    BYTE                byDVRType;
         BYTE               byChanNum;          
} NET_DEVICEINFO, *LPNET_DEVICEINFO;
```

C#:

```
public struct NET_DEVICEINFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 48)]
        public byte[] sSerialNumber;    
        public byte byAlarmInPortNum;       
        public byte byAlarmOutPortNum;      
        public byte byDiskNum;              
        public byte byDVRType;              
        public byte byChanNum;              
    }
```

And This structure Which I want Convert,this has 2 dim Array
C++:

```
typedef struct
{
    DWORD               dwSize;
    DWORD               dwDecProListNum;    
    char                DecProName[DH_MAX_DECPRO_LIST_SIZE][DH_MAX_NAME_LEN]; 
    DH_485_CFG          stDecoder[DH_MAX_DECODER_NUM];  
    DWORD               dw232FuncNameNum;       
    char                s232FuncName[DH_MAX_232FUNCS][DH_MAX_NAME_LEN]; 
    DH_RS232_CFG        st232[DH_MAX_232_NUM];  
} DHDEV_COMM_CFG;
```

and this is my try in C#,But it is giving me an error,
C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct DHDEV_COMM_CFG
    {
        public uint dwSize;
        public uint dwDecProListNum;    
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]
        public string[] DecProName;                             
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        DH_485_CFG[] stDecoder;  
        public uint dw232FuncNameNum;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
        public string[] s232FuncName;                           
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public DH_RS232_CFG[] st232;                             
    } ;
```

Please tell me how to to this....

By Bala

Comment: Do you mind formatting this properly?

Comment: What error are you referring to? Does it compile? Or do you get a run-time error?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda useless 6 years down the road, but in any case, the converter from [here](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CPlusPlus_to_CSharp_Converter_Details.html) worked nicely for me...